# Can we get control in leave event?

Tags: c#, get, controls

When i want to get an control, i can type like this (exp listview):

```
ListView lst = (ListView)this.ActiveControl;
```

But in Leave event, I can't write like that.
So can somebody help me how to get a control at Leave event?
In Leave event it say that control is no longer active. How can we get a control by the way above?

Comment: use the *sender* argument for that

Comment: Cast `sender` to the control type and you're good.

Comment: Btw: This is the recommended way for all events. ActiveControl is only used when you're not in an event.

Comment: Thanks alot TaW and Sir Rufo ^^ it work for me so much ^^

Answer (score -1):

Error occurs because when a control has lost the focus, then it is not active any more. If you want to use your last active control, you can save it using `Enter` event and use it in `Leave`:

**Define a variable inside class:**

```
Control ctlActive = null;
```

**Inside Enter event:**

```
ctlActive = this.ActiveControl;
// OR:
ctlActive = sender as Control;
```

**Inside Leave event:**

```
if (ctlActive != null && ctlActive is ListView)
{
    var lst = ctlActive as ListView;
    // do something...
}
//...
ctlActive = null;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Amin, but comment above i greater, at all, thanks alot for your answer ^^